Seafile client breaks home directory in Ubuntu 24.04
I have a weird bug on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 24.04:
I have my normal home directory with some files in snap, Downloads and Pictures. All other folders are empty:

But as soon as I launch the newly installed Seafile client (not setup or configured!) all my not empty folders in my home directory turn into broken symbolic links:

In between I did nothing but double clicked Seafile and took another screenshot. That seems very weird to me?! I this a problem with Ubuntu or is it rather a problem with Seafile?
